# How to user pm2 and jenkins to run the 'sudo npm start'?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, jenkins, pm2

I have added the jenkins user to had all permission.

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

also installed the `pm2` as globally, and `pm2` need to run command

```
sudo npm start
```

as build process needs to create some directory, if I run `sudo npm start` in the app1 directory it works perfectly however with pm2 command it throws access error

```
sudo pm2 start config.js
```

**config.js**

```
  module.exports = {
      apps : [{
        name   : "app1",
        cwd : "./my-dir/app1,
        script : "sudo npm",
        args : "start"
      },{
        name   : "app2",
        cwd : "./my-dir/app2",
        script : "npm",
        args : "start"
      }]
    }
```

Is it error with pm2 permission or user permission?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: pm2 process runs under each user separately, so you need to start the pm2 process as jenkins users, which will be created while installing the jenkins, also check the sudo permission to jenkins so it can create workspace directory if you want to customise the destination path.  Note: if same process is running under other users, first remove conflicting process and then start config.js file under jenkins user

Comment: isn't it bad to give root privileges to jenkins ?

Comment: allow a group with limited privileges to create files and make jerkins its part,

Comment: In my case I have a Root user which start pm2 for other applications. Jenkins needs it too, but I don't when Jenkins to use sudo. I don't understant your comment, if you could try to explain with more detail that would be cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running the command with all the `sudo` privileges create the user with the least number of privileges that you want to give to your app.

You already have the jenkins set to use `sudo` with no password, so you can use the below command to run the `pm2` from jenkins as other user with least privilege.

```
sudo su - username -c 'pm2 start config.js'
```

The above command will be run as the specified user